# How can I have a \newtheorem... environment refer to its thmnote?

Tags: theorems, amsthm, newtheorem

I'm currently using `\newtheoremstyle` to produce the following output:

[image: current]

> **Question:** How can I easily modify my MWE (see below) so that the *a*'s in my QED boxes say "Name of Thing", "A Different Thing", etc. instead?

Here's what I'd like to have:

[image: desired]

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheoremstyle{underlinenonum}% name
{-1.5mm}           % Space above, empty = `usual value'
{}                 % Space below
{}                 % Body font
{\parindent}       % Indent amount (empty = no indent, \parindent = para indent)
{}                 % Thm head font
{}                 % Punctuation after thm head
{ }                % Space after thm head: \newline = linebreak
{\noindent{\underline{\thmnote{#3:}}}}

\theoremstyle{underlinenonum}
\newtheorem*{subcase}{subcase}
    \let\mtendsubcase\endsubcase
    \renewcommand{\endsubcase}{\renewcommand\qedsymbol{\tiny\fbox{a}}\qed\mtendsubcase}

\begin{document}
    \begin{subcase}[Name of Thing] This is a thing I would like to say.\end{subcase}
    \begin{subcase}[A Different Thing] This is a \textit{different} thing I would like to say, and I need a QED to automatically reflect \textit{its} argument.\end{subcase}
\end{document}
```

Notice that I want to include "Name of Thing", "A Different Thing", etc. as an argument into the `subcase` theorem environment and have the QED box automatically pull from that argument.

Independently, I've tried using `\fbox{\thmnote}}`, etc., instead of `fbox{a}`, but each iteration yields an error. I've also tried Google *and* searching sXe, all to no avail.

**Edit 1:** As noted in the comments below, I **do not** want to manually type the static arguments into the QED boxes, because there will be a number of these environments used successively and I'd like each QED box to reflect its respective `thmnote`.

Comment: Why not just replace `\fbox{a}` with `\fbox{Name of Thing}` ?

Comment: @HafidBoukhoulda - I will have a number of these theorems environments in succession, and their arguments/"Name of Thing" will not be constant. I'll edit my question to show that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the theorem-like environment in a new one where you can more easily absorb the name and use it as you wish.

I changed the syntax for `subcase` to have a mandatory argument, which is semantically sounder. And I removed the underlining: sorry, but I can't stand it.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheoremstyle{underlinenonum}% name
{-1.5mm}           % Space above, empty = `usual value'
{}                 % Space below
{}                 % Body font
{\parindent}       % Indent amount (empty = no indent, \parindent = para indent)
{}                 % Thm head font
{}                 % Punctuation after thm head
{ }                % Space after thm head: \newline = linebreak
{\noindent\textbf{\thmnote{#3:}}}

\theoremstyle{underlinenonum}

\newtheorem*{subcaseinner}{subcase}
\newenvironment{subcase}[1]
 {%
  \renewcommand\qedsymbol{\subcaseqed{#1}}%
  \subcaseinner[#1]%
 }
 {\qed\endsubcaseinner}
\newcommand{\subcaseqed}[1]{\fbox{\tiny #1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{subcase}{Name of Thing}
This is a thing I would like to say.
\end{subcase}

\begin{subcase}{A Different Thing}
This is a \textit{different} thing I would like to say, and I need 
a QED to automatically reflect \textit{its} argument.
\end{subcase}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As always, your amazingness never ceases to impress!